# Reflection should not move at hover with underline

Tags: html, css

My goal is that when the user hovers over the nav the underline should not move the reflection. It should just overlay the reflection. At the moment as soon i hover over the nav elements the underline pushes down the reflection. How can I change this?

I have this code:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <img id="logo" src="http://placekitten.com/440/53"></img>
        <div id="header-address">
            <ul>
                <li>Hagartenstrasse 16 <span> T 032 672 35 84</span></li>
                <li>4562 Biberist <span> F 032 672 15 22</span></li>
                <li>info@malerei-hubler.ch <span> M 079 251 23 22</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li id="reflect" class="navp txtRot"><h1>HOME</h1></li>
            <li id="reflect" class="navp txtOrange"><h1>ANGEBOT</h1></li>
            <li id="reflect" class="navp txtGelb"><h1>TEAM</h1></li>
            <li id="reflect" class="navp txtGruen"><h1>UMWELT</h1></li>
            <li id="reflect" class="txtBlau"><h1>KONTAKT</h1></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body, html, ul, li, h1 {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.container {
    width: 900px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.txtRot {
    color: #e60004;
}
.txtOrange {
    color: #f28e00;
}
.txtGelb {
    color: #f0d80e;
}

.txtGruen {
    color: #009836;
}
.txtBlau {
    color: #0068b5;
}

header {
    margin-top: 56px;
}

ul {
    padding: 0px;
}

/* HEADER */ 
#logo {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#header-address {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#header-address ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}
#header-address ul li {
    line-height: 19px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}#header-address ul li span {
    line-height: 19px;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
nav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
nav ul li  {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
}
nav ul li h1  {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 100%;
    padding:0px;
}
/* PADDING FOR NAV */
.navp {
    padding-right: 46.4px;
    height: 100%;
}

#reflect h1:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid;

}
#reflect {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-reflect: below -3px -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, transparent 70%, transparent 100%);
}


#reflect:before {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box, -moz-element(#reflect) no-repeat scroll 0 -127px content-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    height: 140px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 277px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    width: 360px;
}
```

Here is the codepen:

http://codepen.io/patrickhofer/pen/JKdgVN

Any help much appreciated.

It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
#reflect h1 {
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;

}
#reflect h1:hover{
    border-bottom: 4px solid currentcolor;

}
```

Note you can not have multiple [ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-id) in the same document read [ID selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors)

> Defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole
>   document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a
>   fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

so the final result shall look like this

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

/*Reset Safari User Agent Styles*/

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body,
html,
ul,
li,
h1 {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.container {
  width: 900px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.txtRot {
  color: #e60004;
}
.txtOrange {
  color: #f28e00;
}
.txtGelb {
  color: #f0d80e;
}
.txtGruen {
  color: #009836;
}
.txtBlau {
  color: #0068b5;
}
header {
  margin-top: 56px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0px;
}
/* HEADER */

#logo {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#header-address {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#header-address ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}
#header-address ul li {
  line-height: 19px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#header-address ul li span {
  line-height: 19px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
nav ul li h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
/* PADDING FOR NAV */

.navp {
  padding-right: 46.4px;
  height: 100%;
}
.reflect h1 {
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}
.reflect h1:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid currentcolor;
}
.reflect {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below -3px -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, transparent 70%, transparent 100%);
}
.reflect:before {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box, -moz-element(#reflect) no-repeat scroll 0 -127px content-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  content: "";
  height: 140px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 277px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <img id="logo" src="http://placekitten.com/440/53"></img>
    <div id="header-address">
      <ul>
        <li>Hagartenstrasse 16 <span> T 032 672 35 84</span>
        </li>
        <li>4562 Biberist <span> F 032 672 15 22</span>
        </li>
        <li>info@malerei-hubler.ch <span> M 079 251 23 22</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="reflect navp txtRot">
        <h1>HOME</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="reflect navp txtOrange">
        <h1>ANGEBOT</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="reflect navp txtGelb">
        <h1>TEAM</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="reflect navp txtGruen">
        <h1>UMWELT</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="reflect txtBlau">
        <h1>KONTAKT</h1>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

you can use [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) too

```
.reflect h1:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px;
}
```

that will look like this

```css
* {

  margin: 0px;

  padding: 0px;

}

body,

html,

ul,

li,

h1 {

  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;

  font-size: 100%;

  line-height: 1em;

}

.container {

  width: 900px;

  height: 100vh;

  margin: 0 auto;

}

h1,

h2,

h3 {

  font-weight: 600;

}

.txtRot {

  color: #e60004;

}

.txtOrange {

  color: #f28e00;

}

.txtGelb {

  color: #f0d80e;

}

.txtGruen {

  color: #009836;

}

.txtBlau {

  color: #0068b5;

}

header {

  margin-top: 56px;

}

ul {

  padding: 0px;

}

/* HEADER */

#logo {

  height: 100%;

  float: left;

}

#header-address {

  font-weight: 400;

  font-style: italic;

  font-size: 14px;

}

#header-address ul {

  list-style: none;

  float: right;

}

#header-address ul li {

  line-height: 19px;

  text-transform: uppercase;

}

#header-address ul li span {

  line-height: 19px;

  float: right;

  padding-left: 5px;

}

nav {

  float: left;

  margin-top: 60px;

  margin-left: 0px;

}

nav ul li {

  display: inline-block;

  list-style: none;

  margin-bottom: 50px;

}

nav ul li h1 {

  font-size: 40px;

  font-weight: 600;

  height: 100%;

  padding: 0px;

}

/* PADDING FOR NAV */

.navp {

  padding-right: 46.4px;

  height: 100%;

}


.reflect h1:hover {

  box-shadow: 0 4px;

}

.reflect {

  position: relative;

  -webkit-box-reflect: below -3px -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, transparent 70%, transparent 100%);

}

.reflect:before {

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box, -moz-element(#reflect) no-repeat scroll 0 -127px content-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

  content: "";

  height: 140px;

  left: 0;

  position: absolute;

  top: 277px;

  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);

  transform: scaleY(-1);

  width: 360px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <img id="logo" src="http://placekitten.com/440/53" />
    <div id="header-address">
      <ul>
        <li>Hagartenstrasse 16 <span> T 032 672 35 84</span>
        </li>
        <li>4562 Biberist <span> F 032 672 15 22</span>
        </li>
        <li>info@malerei-hubler.ch <span> M 079 251 23 22</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="reflect navp txtRot">
        <h1>HOME</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="reflect navp txtOrange">
        <h1>ANGEBOT</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="reflect navp txtGelb">
        <h1>TEAM</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="reflect navp txtGruen">
        <h1>UMWELT</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="reflect txtBlau">
        <h1>KONTAKT</h1>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a specific height to `navp`. You can try changing your `.navp` like this:

```
.navp {
   padding-right: 46.4px;
   height: 40px;
   margin-bottom:7px;
 }
```